# Emulating an AARCH64 Binary calling libgps on x86_64 Ubuntu using QEMU gives "Error relocating: symbol not found" Errors

Tags: qemu, glibc, gdb, reverse-engineering, gpsd

This is similar to the issue posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/619800/i-get-many-error-relocating-symbol-not-found-errors-when-trying-to-run-an-arm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64851884/problems-with-using-qemu-user-mode-to-run-an-arm64-binary). I want to reverse engineer a binary called **gpslogger** but before debugging it using GDB, I wish to simply emulate it using QEMU (qemu-aarch64) since when I run `file gpslogger` I get `gpslogger: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1, not stripped`. I start by downloading the exact interpreter file and pasting it in my Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 `/lib` folder and then other errors show up asking for other `.so` files, e.g., `libgps.so`. I then download those `.so` files for the AARCH64 architecture and paste them in the `/lib` folder of my Ubuntu. Once all the `.so` errors, i.e., `no such file or directory` are gone, I'm left with

```
Error relocating /lib/libgps.so: __strdup: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgps.so: __fdelt_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgps.so: __fprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgps.so: __snprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgps.so: __isnan: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgps.so: __syslog_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgps.so: __vsnprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libdbus-1.so.3: __snprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libdbus-1.so.3: __vsnprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libdbus-1.so.3: __strncpy_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libdbus-1.so.3: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libdbus-1.so.3: __fprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libdbus-1.so.3: __vsprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __sprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: reallocarray: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __register_atfork: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __memcpy_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __snprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __vsnprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __strncpy_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __vasprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __open64_2: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __asprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __fprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __ppoll_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: fcntl64: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __explicit_bzero_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: parse_printf_format: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libsystemd.so.0: __openat64_2: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgcrypt.so.20: __memcpy_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgcrypt.so.20: __snprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgcrypt.so.20: __fdelt_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgcrypt.so.20: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgcrypt.so.20: __memset_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgcrypt.so.20: __fprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgcrypt.so.20: __read_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgcrypt.so.20: __syslog_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgpg-error.so.0: __sprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgpg-error.so.0: __fdelt_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgpg-error.so.0: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgpg-error.so.0: __memset_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /lib/libgpg-error.so.0: __fprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating gpslogger: GPSNMEA: symbol not found
```

Except for the last relocation error, I believe all the other functions should be implemented in `glibc`. Therefore, I simply downloaded the `libc-2.32.so` file from [here](https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/aarch64/glibc) for the AARCH64 architecture and pasted it in the `/lib` folder of my Ubuntu. However, the errors didn't go away. Please let me know if more information is needed. I appreciate any help on the issue.

**Edit:**

`readelf -d gpslogger  | grep 'NEEDED'` returns:

`0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgps.so]`

`0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.musl-aarch64.so.1]`

Does this mean that the `libc` is coming from `musl` and is not `glibc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“interpreter `/lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1`” in `file`’s output indicates that `gpslogger` was built with musl. This means that you need not only the musl dynamic linker (`ld-musl-aarch64.so.1`), but you also need musl variants of every single library used by `gpslogger`.

The missing symbols you list indicate that the libraries you’ve installed were built for glibc.

Comment: Is there any place I can download these shared library files already built using musl? Otherwise I have to build them using a machine with aarch64 architecture running musl, correct?